# I have a list of links that are supposed to be left aligned. One is not aligning

Tags: css, text-alignment

Here is a link to the page. The Home button is supposed to be aligned directly above the Gallery button. Can anyone help me out?

http://amfotography.com/newsite/contact.html

Comment: You've got some broken HTML which may not be helping there is no such thing as a `<class>` tag. Perhaps you mean the class attribute to specify a css class for the tag.

Comment: Your page has at least 27 errors according to the W3 validator. You're using elements like 'class' which aren't element. Try cleaning up the code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pageoff a {
    display: block;
}
```

That would work in your current layout.

However, your HTML is a problem, there is no "class" element - change all to a div and it will fix itself.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it with the exception of one thing. Now the last clients link is defaulting to white. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure which link you mean now, elaborate more please? In any case, I'd like to stress the validity of your code - at the very least you might want use HTML tags that exist. Making up tags is, well.. not recommended and can have many undesired and random consequences.

Answer (score 1):

change your

```
<class id="pageoff">

</class>
```

to

```
<div id="pageoff">

</div>
```

Just to elaborate as well I would change all your  tags to valid HTML markup.  I would suggest using  on any menu items you have on the left and  to wrap around content.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your highest level menu items are wrapped in `<class id="pageoff">`

Change:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

to:

```
<p>
    <class id="pageoff">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </class>
</p>
```

There is also an extra `<br />` above the `class` for Galleries you will want to remove to have it directly above.